# error while running roboearth on groovy

Tags: ros-fuerte, ros-groovy, roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I am trying to run roboearth_stack on ros-groovy, ubuntu 12.04 lts machine without much success. Though I have tried it earlier on fuerte and it works perfectly, I am not too sure if its possible to run it on groovy. Has anyone tried it yet?

This is the output of rosmake roboearth:

### [rosmake-1] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2
No Makefile in package opencv2
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge
No Makefile in package cv_bridge
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> class_loader [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< class_loader ROS_NOBUILD in package class_loader
No Makefile in package class_loader
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib
No Makefile in package pluginlib
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport
No Makefile in package image_transport
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> visualization_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< visualization_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package visualization_msgs
No Makefile in package visualization_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> resource_retriever [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< resource_retriever ROS_NOBUILD in package resource_retriever
No Makefile in package resource_retriever
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> ar_pose [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosprolog [PASS] [ 3.21 seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> semweb [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< tf_prolog [PASS] [ 3.29 seconds ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> ias_prolog_addons [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< re_msgs [PASS] [ 6.22 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> re_srvs [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< semweb [PASS] [ 3.30 seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> knowrob_common [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< ias_prolog_addons [PASS] [ 3.28 seconds ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> re_2dmap_extractor [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< ar_pose [PASS] [ 4.68 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> re_vision [ make ]
[ rosmake ] Last 40 lines_srvs: 9.1 sec ] [ knowrob_common: 8.8 sec ] [ re_2dmap_extractor: 8.7 sec ] [... [ 4 Active 64/93 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ 51%] Built target createPlyPoints
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/build' make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/build'
[ 53%] Built target createPointCloudModel
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/build' make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/build'
[ 56%] Built target extractOutlineFromImages
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/build' make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/build'
[ 59%] Built target extractSurf
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/build' make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/build'
[ 62%] Built target removeBackgroundPoints
In file included from /home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/src/ObjectDetectorClass.h:39:0,
from /home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/src/ObjectDetectorClass.cpp:37:
/home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/src/ObjectDetectorProvider.h:42:32: fatal error: cv_bridge/CvBridge.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
[ 64%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ObjectDetectorFunctions.dir/src/SurfPlanarDetector.cpp.o
/home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/src/ObjectDetectorProvider.cpp:39:32: fatal error: cv_bridge/CvBridge.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/src/ObjectDetectorMethod.h:41:0,
from /home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/src/ObjectDetectorMethod.cpp:36:
/home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/src/VisualizationManager.h:38:32: fatal error: cv_bridge/CvBridge.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/src/ObjectDetectorMethod.h:41:0,
from /home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/src/SurfPlanarDetector.h:37,
from /home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/src/SurfPlanarDetector.cpp:33:
/home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/src/VisualizationManager.h:38:32: fatal error: cv_bridge/CvBridge.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/ObjectDetectorFunctions.dir/src/ObjectDetectorClass.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/ObjectDetectorFunctions.dir/src/ObjectDetectorProvider.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/ObjectDetectorFunctions.dir/src/ObjectDetectorMethod.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/ObjectDetectorFunctions.dir/src/SurfPlanarDetector.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ObjectDetectorFunctions.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gautam/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/build'

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package re_vision written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/gautam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130809-172211/re_vision/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< re_vision [FAIL] [ 8.18 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package re_vision.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< re_srvs [PASS] [ 14.24 seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< knowrob_common [PASS] [ 17.12 seconds ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< re_2dmap_extractor [PASS] [ 25.48 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 68 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/gautam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130809-172211

I my opinion the problem is with roboearth packages as they mainly support ros- fuerte, so my question is, will these packages run in groovy?if yes, how? and If not, is there any other way to run roboearth in ros-groovy?

I would be happy to provide any other detail regarding this issue.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71938/error-while-running-roboearth-on-groovy/) by [gautam2410](https://answers.ros.org/users/5500/gautam2410/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2013-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a number of different issues involved in running the `roboearth_stack` package on ROS Groovy. I wrote down the solution to most of them [here](https://github.com/Boanerghes/dream/wiki/Migrating-Roboearth-to-ROS-Groovy), and even though it might not be complete, it should address quite a lot of the known problems.

---

Originally posted by [micpalmia](https://answers.ros.org/users/6343/micpalmia/) with karma: 58 on 2013-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gautam2410](https://answers.ros.org/users/5500/gautam2410/) on 2013-09-03**:
Thank you for your reply and for addressing the problem of roboearth with groovy. I will try to follow your solution and then discuss further.

**Comment by [rmb209](https://answers.ros.org/users/14126/rmb209/) on 2014-04-09**:
Just wondering whether you managed to get roboearth stack to work with groovy?

**Comment by [Michele Palmia](https://answers.ros.org/users/4909/michele-palmia/) on 2014-04-11**:
I linked my solution in the response, the procedure is a bit messy but it works.